# change a group of guest host os password in VM

Tags: virtual-machines, password

I am the build guy and need to manage 300-500 build machines in a VM host for company. Now I need to change password for all machine's "build" account Do I have a way to change it without log-in into each machine?

Comment: Using a central managing system and/or central authentication would really be useful in your case. Anyway answering your question without even knowing virtualization technology or OS in use is not easy.

Comment: You really should have these systems join a domain (e.g. Active Directory for Windows or FreeIPA for Linux).

Comment: Or just use AD with Linux and Samba..

Answer (score 1):

You don't give details on your platform, but in the *NIX world you'd use a [configuration management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software).

An example with [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/):

```
user { 'build':
  ensure           => 'present',
  comment          => 'Build User,,,',
  gid              => '5000',
  groups           => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
  home             => '/path/to/home',
  password         => '$6$WxRRM9KzacshcnY4dETrcx8vc3GkGfMvoS3sQoYRzch9o1',
  password_max_age => '99999',
  password_min_age => '0',
  shell            => '/bin/bash-static',
  uid              => '5000',
}
```